# how to step backwards through revisions

Tags: svn

Is there an easy way to compare a given revision to its last change? I'm looking or a shortcut similar to `svn diff file.ext -PREV:HEAD`, but with prev relative to a given revision number instead of HEAD.

For example:

Suppose I have a repository on at r10 and file that has been modified in r1, 2, 3, 8, 9. `svn diff -rPREV:HEAD` will give me a diff of r8:10, which is essential the same as r8:9. But if I want a diff of 8 vs its previous state (r3) is there any way to diff without looking at its log, seeing when it was changed and explicitly specifying r3? -rPREV:8 would be diffing r8 to r8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expanding on @Ben Reser's suggestion to use `svn log --diff`

If given a file at r911, and its last change between r900 and r901 (file@r911 is the same as file@r901 and file@901 is different than file@r900)

`svn log filename --diff -r911:0 --l 1`
will return the diff between r901:900, which is essentially the same as diff r911:900

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking this.  In your example a file changes in r1, 2, 3, 8, and 9.  You don't need to specify `svn diff -r 3:8 file.ext` to get the changes made in revision 8, you can do `svn diff -r 7:8 file.ext` to do that.  Since the file wasn't changed in revision 7 it will be the same as the file in 3.  To make it even easier Subversion provides the `-c` flag which does the subtraction for you.  So in your example you can just use `svn diff -c 8 file.ext`

Comment: sorry. my example wasn't clear, say I pull -rPREV:HEAD, I am presented with a diff along with revision info that I am comparing r10 to r8. Based on that info, I want to diff r8 to its previous (r7), sure, I can do -r7:8. But if I want to step back again, I would do r?:7 I'm looking for is -r?:7... Given any revision N and previous (and different) version M, I'm looking for something that would do -rM:N automagically without looking at the log

Comment: If you're just trying to see the history of a file just run log on the file.  If you want to see diffs with the history use the --diff option.  The diff command exists to show you what changed between revisions.  log exists to show you when changes were made.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of log option --diff. Combined with -rM:0 -l 1 , this exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To go back further than you're currently doing with `PREV`, you will need to know the revision numbers themselves.

Note that `PREV` only works when you're referencing a working copy in the first place (and therefore if that WC isn't fully up to date, `PREV` may not be what you think it should be), so you'll have to know revision numbers *anyway* if you're working with repository URLs.